# I need to run the grafana application on two private servers so that when we use the dns of the load balancer the application open

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-security-group

I have two private servers in two availability zones with private ips and a bastion host which is a public server with public ip.I need to run the grafana application on the private servers so that when we use the dns of the load balancer the grafana application opens.I made the target group with port 3000 which is the port of the application and the listening port of the app load balancer as 3000 and attached the two private instances to the target group.I installed the application on the private server using the bastion  host ssh.
Still its not working.

I created two private application servers on private servers on two different availability zones and a public server on a public subnet acting as a bastion host.I installed the grafana app on the private servers using remote connection through bastion host.Then I created a target group with port 3000 which is the port of the app and attached the private instances to the  target group.Then I created the load balancer and attached the target group to it and gave the listening port 3000.Its showing two unhealthy instances in the target group.So what should I do.Im new to this
[The 3 instances I created 2 on private subnet and one on public subnet ,installed grafana on the private server through ssh on the public server grafana is running on both the servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFNiS.png)
[the target group I created its showing 2 unhealthy instances after health check gave the port 3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6BSW.png)
[this is the load balancer i have chosen two different availability zones in ]
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB67y.png)
[these are the inbound rules of the security group I created for the load balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY1xH.png)
[these are the inbound rules of the security group I created for the load balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY80F.png)
The listener ports of the load balancer i gave as 3000
wat should be the configuration pls help me Im new to this

Comment: have you checked to make sure your security group rules allow port 3000 from load balancer to app servers?

Comment: please attach some screenshots and configuration what you did